# Beef jerky to Israel

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, israel

For the purposes of customs, is beef jerky considered a raw meat product? 
In other words, can I bring beef jerky from the US to Israel?

Comment: Are you planning on taking several hundred dollars worth?

Comment: @CGCampbell possibly --I want to have for my own personal use, but don't really want to just "smuggle" it in through the green line if it's not allowed..

Comment: "Smuggle" with or without quotes is never a good idea but into *Israel* ? That is a spectacularly bad idea, my friend.

Comment: @chx I said I *don't * want to because it's the law. (even though I suspect no one would notice anything due to the "green line")

Comment: When I entered Israel a few days ago (via TLV) they were randomly X-raying peoples bags from the "Green Line"

Answer (score 5):

As I indicated in the other question, import of [non-Kosher meat is prohibited](http://www.moital.gov.il/NR/exeres/5EA6B0B6-D877-48D7-A21F-BE9337BFA06A.htm) [Israeli government website, in English]. I see no exception for quantities brought in with you. Kosher beef jerky is available in the USA, but the coals-to-Newcastle aspect is noticeable.

Comment: I didn't know that! I wonder which other countries use "public morals" as a reason to deny import.

Comment: FYI the link doesn't work anymore. There is a version up on the Internet Archive, but I wouldn't know if that's up to date or not.

Comment: Working link - [The relevant law in Hebrew](https://www.nevo.co.il/law_html/Law01/165_002.htm) - prohibits the import of non-Kosher meat, with no mention of quantity. I'm sure it's not enforced on individuals with small amounts (but of course - don't blame me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Food is always iffy on the border but as far as I am aware beef jerky is raw meat and you can't import raw meat into Israel without a license.